# Any way to sign an apk file without using eclipse

Tags: apk, signing

I have an app which I want to sign and publish. I did not develop the app using eclipse. I have very little idea about programming. I have searched a lot of forums but could not find a way to do it. Can anyone explain the procedure to do it without using eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 - You haven't done so, you'll need to create a new key, open the command line and type:**

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt \
 -alias      eclipse \
 -dname "CN=first and last name" \
 -keystore "c:\path\keyname.key" \
 -storepass password \
 -keypass password \
 -keyalg RSA \
 -keysize 2048 \
 -validity 10000
```

**2 - Now you must sign the APK:**

```
JAVA_HOME/bin/jarsigner 
 -verbose
 -keystore c:\path\keyname.key
 -storepass password
 -keypass password
 -signedjar DEV_HOME/bin/AndroidTest.signed.apk DEV_HOME/bin/AndroidTest.unsigned.apk AndroidTestKey
```

**3 - Last step is to zipalign:**

```
ANDROID_HOME/tools/zipalign 
-v 
-f 4  DEV_HOME/bin/AndroidTest.signed.apk DEV_HOME/bin/AndroidTest.apk
```

**NOTES:**
`DEV_HOME` is the location of you project
`ANDROID_HOME` is the Android SDK location
`JAVA_HOME` is the Java location

Comment: Could u please explain that first part of how to generate key a bit more clearly and what are the tools that I need for this

Comment: did you manage to build the apk from the command line? if so, you should mark the answer as correct by clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: Should I install jdk for generating key?

Comment: you must install java and have, at least, the zipalign tool available.

Comment: I have generated the key but when I try to open jarsigner it says directory or syntax is incorrect

Comment: Try double quoting the path,  like this : `"c:\path\keyname.key"`

Answer (score 0):

Signing process is documented here: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html